# can i use my own website to show my youtube playlist and video player?

Tags: video, youtube, playlist

can i use my own website to show my youtube playlist and when someone clicks on a video on that playlist it will play still on my own website? the youtube player also should be beside the playlist on my own website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) for the playlists, and embed the videos in your site.

Comment: yeah but can u click on that playlist and see that video playing on the same window? i was thinking it will redirect on the youtube page instead of staying on my own website? which parameters i need to change in order to achieve this? or where exactly is it stated in youtube api docs? thank you!!

Comment: You can play it on your site, or on YT, it's up to you. What language are you using?

Comment: PHP, joomla, i cant seem to find that article in youtube api docs can you point me to it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with PHP or Joomla, but this should be of use for the playlist:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Playlists_Feeds

To make sure the video plays in your site, you need to embed it. Each video has a special link for videos you want embedded. You can find the link here:
http://google.about.com/od/googleblogging/ss/embedyoutubesbs.htm